# Mule 4 - Flow Design Scheduled

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mule4

I have a problem when the scheduled  starts, it has a subsequent process that lasts longer than each interval, that is, every 2 seconds it starts the process, but if it takes 4 seconds to finish, my problem is that I don't know how to prevent the interval from starting. until the last task is completed.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the max concurrency attribute of the flow to 1.